# Which part of the memory does the string get stored in?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Here is a piece of C code that I was asked to analyze in an interview.

```
int main() {
    char *ptr = "hello"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Which part of the memory does the string "hello" get stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is implementation-specific and not specified by the standard.  You'd have to consult the documentation for your particular compiler to determine where it's placed.

Generally, compilers place string literals in a read-only data segment such as the code segment.  This allows multiple different string literals to be encoded in the program using a single piece of memory, which can be shared.  It's also why it's a Bad Idea to try to modify a string literal in-place, since this often triggers a segmentation fault due to writing to a read-only segment.  This isn't guaranteed, but it's often implemented this way.